# Can't use keyboard when resuming from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake

On a Macbook Pro, with Lion: I usually set it to sleep at the end of the working day, and resume from sleep in the morning. Sometimes, I can't type the password after resume, and I have to reboot it the hard way, because the left side of the keyboard isn't responding (I can only type on the right side).

Is it a common problem, or is it just on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it can take a while for the sleepimage to make the login/password field active (there should be a blue line round the inside of the box when its active). I've noticed this behaviour in both 10.7 and 10.8 (but not in 10.6) on occasion, but no consistently. Usually when it happens it takes about 10 secs or so before I can type.

However, if you're saying you can type some characters (from the right side of the keyb) but not others (those on the left) that sounds most definitely like a hardware issue.

Try connecting an external keyboard and seeing if the problem appears on that too. If no, you've a hardware issue. If yes, post back.

Comment: Ok with external keyboard. But that's not a great solution... :-/

Comment: No, but it suggests you need to take the mac in to a shop to have the internal keyboard repaired!

Comment: Since it happens only on sleep/resume, and it's already out of warranty, no. I set the default sleep to hibernate, and it's working perfectly. When it breaks, I'll have it repaired, not before. Thanks anyway.